# How to play a game on your PC while processing it on another PC

Tags: windows, windows-11, gaming, steam

I bought [WILD HEARTS](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1938010/WILD_HEARTS/) from Steam on my brother's [PC (PC①)] that he bought 3 years ago, but I can't play the game as much as I want because it doesn't have enough specs.

[My PC](https://www.mouse-jp.co.jp/store/g/gdaiv-x7/) (PC②) has sufficient specs to run WILD HEARTS, but since I am using it most of the time, I thought it would be ideal to process the game in the background on PC② (while I can do other work on PC②) and play the game on PC①.

I tried the streaming function of Steam, but I could not control the game from PC① unless WILD HEARTS was displayed on the screen of PC② and the WILD HEARTS window was focused, so I could not do what I wanted after all.

Next, I tried connecting PC② to a sub-monitor (TV), displaying the game screen on the sub-monitor, and thought that if I used Steam streaming on PC①, I could play the game on PC① and do other work on PC②. However, every time I operated the game from PC①, the mouse and focus of PC② were adjusted to the game on the sub-monitor, and in the end I could not operate the game on the main monitor of PC②.

Next, we created a new Windows user on PC② (existing user①, new user②) and
I thought that if I started the game as user② and then switched the PC user to user① (not a signout), I could work on PC② while my brother played the game. However, for some reason, the game could not be started as user②.

Please let me know if there is a way to start WILD HEARTS on this user② or if there is another way to do other work while processing the game on PC②.

### PC Specs

#### PC①

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H Processer (9core / 12threads / 2.60GHz[max4.50GHz] / 12MB Cache)
- Memory: 16GB [ 8GB×2 ( PC4-21300 / DDR4-2666 ) ]
- SSD:  512GB NVM Express SSD ( M.2 PCI Express )
- HDD: 2TB
- Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce MX250 / 2GB
- OS: Windows 11 64bit

#### PC②

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900X Processer (10core / 20threads / 3.70GHz / 19.25MB Cache)
- Memory: 64GB [16GB×4 (DDR4-3200)]
- SSD: 512GB NVM Express SSD (M.2 PCI Express)
- HDD: 2TB
- Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX3060 / 12GB
- OS: Windows 11 64bit

Comment: Pretty much that's how steam remote play works. it's a type of descktop sharing: your game runs in the foreground on the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You may install Steam to your computer and logon with your brother's
account and play the game.

There are some limitations : One steam account can be login to
multiple computers but only one computer with this steam account can be
online and play multiplayer games.

You might get around it by playing the game offline, but I haven't
tried it.